# In WordPress post per page is not working when use exclude ids from the query

Tags: wordpress

I have few feature post which i have to exclude from all post so I have used `post__not_in` but it return all post instead of `posts-per-page` 6 post how to fix this isssue.

```
$exclude_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post__not_in'      => $exclude_ids,
    'orderby'           => 'publish_date',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts-per-page'    => 6
);

$latest_post = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its just a typo but the correct param is "posts_per_page" not "posts-per-page" (dash vs underscore) (see here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters)

```
$exclude_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post__not_in'      => $exclude_ids,
    'orderby'           => 'publish_date',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => 6
);

$latest_post = new WP_Query( $args );
```